# Windows 7 End of Support - How to get OLD updates / patches thereafter?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-update, updates

Today is the End of Life for Windows 7. Of course MS will not release new updates or patches for Windows 7 anymore.

If I install a new PC by a Windows 7 disc from scratch, I would expect I will not be able to download the Windows Updates. When I open "Windows Update" and check for updates, I would expect nothing will be found. (Correct?)

However in the MS website, there is a [**Microsoft Update Catalog**](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/). It seems that we can download all the updates from there. As we all know Windows XP was EOL years ago. We can still find Windows XP updates from there.

Let me assume that the **Microsoft Update Catalog** contains ALL the updates and patches for Windows 7 now. (Correct?)

And let me assume that the Windows 7 updates and patches will still be available (for a few years) in the **Microsoft Update Catalog** even after Windows 7 EOL. (Correct?)

As MS is actually still hosting the update files in their server (the **Microsoft Update Catalog**), why MS does not keep steaming those OLD updates and patches to users through the OS built in "Windows Update" service?

Comment: To encourage stragglers to adopt the new operating system version, to free up server resources in the data center and retire old services, there are many possible reasons why Microsoft may have elected to do this.

Comment: You will be able currently release updates after the EOL date for Windows 7 just like you can download currently released updates for Windows XP.  Your question is based upon an incorrect assumption.

Answer (score 3):

> If I install a new PC by a Windows 7 disc from scratch, I would expect I will not be able to download the Windows Updates. When I open "Windows Update" and check for updates, I would expect nothing will be found. (Correct?)

You would be mistaken.  Any Windows 7 update currently available will be available after the EOL for Windows 7.  Microsoft is still providing updates to those customers that have paid for support.  While those updates won’t be published on Windows Updates the currently released updates still have to be available to those customers.

> Let me assume that the Microsoft Update Catalog contains ALL the updates and patches for Windows 7 now. (Correct?)

The catalog has the currently released updates.  It doesn’t actually contain every update ever released for Windows 7.

> And let me assume that the Windows 7 updates and patches will still be available (for a few years) in the Microsoft Update Catalog even after Windows 7 EOL. (Correct?)

Microsoft absolutely will not be removing the currently released Windows 7 updates from the catalog.  Windows XP updates can still be downloaded.  You can install and patch Windows XP today.

> As MS is actually still hosting the update files in their server (the Microsoft Update Catalog), why MS does not keep steaming those OLD updates and patches to users through the OS built in "Windows Update" service?

You would have to ask Microsoft the reason they have chooses to continue to support Windows 7 to enterprise customers and not remove Windows 7 updates from the Windows Update Catalog.

> Why MS does not provide convenience download of OLD updates for EOL OS?

Microsoft provides any number of methods to manage updates on their operating systems.  These methods will not suddenly stop working once a Windows version is no longer supported.  It took years for Windows 2000 to stop being supported after it reached EOL and was primarily dropped due to software no longer supporting it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive answer and the good news. It is glad to know that I can still get OLD Windows 7 updates through the OS directly. But I cannot find any places mentioning about this. It would be nice if you could quote a reference.

Comment: May I ask which types of updates / patches are included in the Microsoft Update Catalog, and which types are not.

Comment: I guess MS provides extended paid support to Win7 Ent customers because of pressures. And Windows Update Catalog is acting as an archive, just as you said, MS will not remove them for integrity, i guess. It is nice of MS to make these files publicly available.

Comment: @midnite - I have no references.  I just know Microsoft, I know that Windows XP updates are still available after all these years, so I know what will happen once Windows 7 is EOL.  I know that Microsoft is supporting customers within the Enterprise sector willing to pay for Windows 7 updates.  While any updates released of the EOL date for Windows 7 will be distributed directly to those customers, the existing updates must be distributed through the catalog.  As for which updates are in the catalog, the current updates, Microsoft does not distribute a patch once it's been superseded.