# Do I get latest possible update now for obsolete Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-update

Now, when Windows 7 support has discontinued, if I install brand new Windows 7 on my machine (my laptop has possibility to make a factory reset), will it still get all updates automatically from the point it was launched up to 2020 Jan. 14? Do the same rules apply for Windows 8? Is there a way to download and install all of these updates manually if automatic update fails?

Comment: [Why MS does not provide convenience download of OLD updates for EOL OS?](https://superuser.com/questions/1517032/why-ms-does-not-provide-convenience-download-of-old-updates-for-eol-os) is current and probably has some of the information you're looking for.

Comment: @Seth great find, thank you!

Comment: @slhck yes, pretty much. You probably want me to remove my question, but for some reason I can't find this function from my phone

Comment: Sorry, the comment you received was auto-generated by the system (I find its wording rather confusing). You don't have to do anything. Your question will be marked as a duplicate once enough users vote for it. I think you may be able to do that yourself on the desktop version.